# Violation of conservation of energy... or not?

Tags: energy-conservation, work, potential-energy, surface-tension, capillary-action

The work done by surface tension is double the increase in potential energy. This is a clear violation of conservation of energy. What is the flaw here?

Work done by surface tension is
\begin{align}
W&=T\cos\theta\cdot h\cdot2\pi r\\
&=T\cos\theta\left(\frac{2T\cos\theta}{\rho gr}\right)2\pi r\\
&=\frac{4T^2(\cosθ)^2\pi}{\rho g}
\end{align}

Increase in potential energy is
\begin{align}
P&=πr^2h\rho g\cdot\frac h2\\
&=\frac{2T^2(cosθ)^2\pi}{\rho g}
\end{align}

Where did the other half go or is there some error in the calculations? The height increased in potential energy calculation is $h/2$ as it is of the center of mass.

Comment: Is this a "check my work" question? (Serious question because I don't understand what qualifies as "check my work" and what doesn't.)

Comment: @DanielSank This is a bit of a grey area; he's asking to check if there's an error in the calculations, but if there isn't then he wants a physical interpretation of his results. So I think it may be on topic.

Comment: @JamalS: Ok, so "check my work" problems can be made on-topic by appending "...and if I'm wrong what is the physical principle behind my error"?

;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a [check-my-work question](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583).

Answer (score 0):

You must use h and not h/2, because h is the height of whatever (such as a wire) that is feeling the tension force. Same as a mass attached to a spring, you use the extension of the spring, not the center of mass of the spring.